# Two column float with [t] using the cas-dc template

Tags: floats, templates, els-cas

I am using the `cas-dc` template for Elsevier. When trying to use `\begin{figure*}[t]`, except I get the error `'The module 'cas/fig' does not have a key called 'cas/fig/t'.` Other templates I use work fine. I have included `\usepackage{stfloats}`. I don't see anything mentioned that strictly forbids it, unless I missed this. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `els-cas` templates redefine LaTeX's `figure` environment, so the syntax changed. Instead of `\begin{figure*}[t]` you need to use `\begin{figure*}[pos=t]`.

The optional argument now allows you to change other things as well, such as the alignment, spacing before and after the figure and caption, so that you can have a nice inconsistent document layout ;-)

Comment: `pos=p` does not seems to work well. Why do they have to redefine `figure`? Is there a way to redefine it back?